# How long after the application deadline does it take a search committee to schedule telephone interviews?

Tags: job-search, faculty-application

I know this can vary from department to department but in general how long does it take for a search committee to decide on a short-list of candidates once the deadline for submission has passed?

Comment: This is so variable; throw-in Covid so lots of stuff is done by email rather than in person, and who knows?

Comment: In my experience, hiring timelines are much more variable than people tell me they are.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @physicist It may be hard to give an objective answer, but I don't think the question is a duplicate and I am interested to see any additional possible responses.

Comment: Please remember that in the 90% of the cases deadlines are absolutely arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a matter of weeks normally: from within one week to a month or two tops.

There is a need to have a meeting to agree on the candidates, and the committee members need to look at the candidates beforehand, which can amount to hundreds of initial candidates.

Comment: one week would be lightning fast in my world.